# Using timestamp URL while signing via Java Security APIs

Tags: java, security, digital-signature

I have a requirement wherein I need to sign and verify a file using Java security APIs.
I am able to achieve signing using PFX file and using Certificate file while verification.

But my problem is that I have to use cross certificate file and timestamp also while signing.I am unable to find anything as to how a timestamp URL(http://timestamp.verisign.com/scripts/timstamp.dll) can be used while signing and what would be its significance.

Can anyone please look into this help me in resolving the same.

```
fileInputStream = new FileInputStream("Path of file to be signed");

            if (fileInputStream != null) {
                bufferedInputStream = new BufferedInputStream(
                        fileInputStream);

                byte[] buffer = new byte[DigitalSignatureConstants.BYTE_SIZE];
                int bufferedInputStreamLength;

                while (bufferedInputStream.available() != DigitalSignatureConstants.ZERO_LENGTH) {

                    bufferedInputStreamLength = bufferedInputStream
                            .read(buffer);
                    dsaSignature.update(buffer,
                            DigitalSignatureConstants.ZERO_LENGTH,
                            bufferedInputStreamLength);
                }
            }
```

byte[] realSig = dsaSignature.sign();

```
        // Save the signature in a file
        String msiFilePath = msiFile;
        if (msiFilePath != null) {
            String result = msiFilePath.substring(
                    DigitalSignatureConstants.ZERO_LENGTH,
                    msiFilePath.lastIndexOf('.'));

            String signatureFilePath = result.concat("SigFile");

            if (signatureFilePath != null) {
                try(FileOutputStream  sigFileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(
                        signatureFilePath)){

                sigFileOutputStream.write(realSig);
                        }
                catch(FileNotFoundException fe)
                {
                    fe.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: @Amy, i have pasted my signing code above.Please see to it and help me in the same.

Comment: can anyone please look into it and help me in the same.